# How to resolve this error:com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect?

Tags: java, networking, ssh, aem, jsch

When I am trying to copy Excel sheet from my local to another windows server. File should be generating automatically at my local for every 3 min, at the time I have to generate in window server. But I got this error below I have mentioned here,
I am using code only you can refer this link:  https://vinaydvd.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/copying-files-from-a-remote-linux-server-to-local-windows-server-using-java/

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.hpe.cdsh.cadence.GenerateExcel.main(GenerateExcel.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Nothing is listening at the target IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: i tried to connect to windows server

Comment: You're trying to connect to a Windows server via Sftp.  Windows doesn't have native SFTP, so unless you installed an SFTP server daemon and it's running on the Windows server, EJP's comment is your answer...nothing is listening at the target IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: Check with following command `telnet <linux hostname> <port no>` from windows command prompt to check if the port is accessible/open to access on the hostname. Idealy it should not accessible in your case.

Comment: < was unexpected at this time.i am getting this error.otherwise can you give example

Comment: What does this have to do with AEM?